# Combining test coverage with hpc

Tags: haskell, code-coverage, haskell-program-coverage

I find hpc really confusing, even after reading several explanations and playing around quite a bit.

I have a library `HML`, and two test suites `fileio-test` and `types-test`, using `HTF` (I plan on moving to `tasty`). I'd like to run the two tests and then see the combined coverage from the two over the library.

At the moment I build the library using

```
cabal configure --enable-coverage
cabal build
```

And run the tests using

```
cabal configure --enable-coverage --enable-tests
cabal build
cabal test

hpc report --hpc-dir dist/hpc/vanilla/mix/fileio-test dist/hpc/vanilla/tix/fileio-test/fileio-test.tix
```

This shows me some coverage, but not the correct one. What I *think* is that it shows coverage, but only from *one* of the tests, and also includes coverage of the tests themselves.

I tried using

```
--hpc-dir dist/hpc/vanilla/mix/HML-0.1.0.0
```

But then hpc complains it can't find the module files it needs. I also tried combining coverage from the two tests with no luck.

Any pointers?

Comment: There are two environment variables, one of which is documented, that determine where the info is dumped. It's all really terrible.

Answer (score 2):

I am also attempting to call HPC directly and have a similar error.

Cabal 3.6 should be able to generate your HPC report for you without needing to call HPC like you describe. It can bypass that error. There is one caveat:
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6440#issuecomment-1133542171

Add to `cabal.project`:

```
package *
  coverage: True
  library-coverage: True
```

then `cabal test`. The report should be somewhere in `dist-newstyle`.

---

Reading the verbose log from `cabal test` with the options above has shown the correct arguments to HPC. It solves the module error.
Here is an example for Mustache: https://github.com/JustusAdam/mustache

Add to `cabal.project`:

```
package *
  coverage: True
  library-coverage: True
```

then `cabal test -v all > foo.log`.

In `foo.log` there should be a call to HPC such as:

```
~/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/bin/hpc markup \
dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/t/unit-tests/hpc/vanilla/tix/unit-tests/unit-tests.tix \
'--destdir=dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/t/unit-tests/hpc/vanilla/html/unit-tests' \
'--hpcdir=dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/hpc/vanilla/mix/unit-tests' \
'--hpcdir=dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/hpc/vanilla/mix/mustache-2.4.0' \
'--include=Text.Mustache' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Types' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Parser' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Compile' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Render'
```

Take that, replace `markup` with `report`, and remove `--destdir`, which gives something like:

```
hpc report dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/t/unit-tests/hpc/vanilla/tix/unit-tests/unit-tests.tix \
'--hpcdir=dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/hpc/vanilla/mix/unit-tests' \
'--hpcdir=dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.7/mustache-2.4.0/hpc/vanilla/mix/mustache-2.4.0' \
'--include=Text.Mustache' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Types' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Parser' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Compile' \
'--include=Text.Mustache.Render'
```

Pasting that into the terminal in the root of the Mustache project yields:

```
 59% expressions used (635/1069)
 28% boolean coverage (4/14)
       0% guards (0/6), 1 always True, 5 unevaluated
      50% 'if' conditions (4/8), 1 always False, 3 unevaluated
     100% qualifiers (0/0)
 41% alternatives used (34/82)
 56% local declarations used (13/23)
 63% top-level declarations used (48/76)
```